# Latest version & IMVU

Tags: mount

I've tried downloading the latest version for my windows pc.  Both times were from the Ubuntu website, one was the normal download link, the other was via the torrent link.

Apart from taking ages to download over fibre opic internet, they were both advertised as iso files.  I tried to mount both downoads to both flash drive & dvd, but neither would mount & neither came up as iso files in my burner.

Is there anywhere i can call to get it on dvd?  I tried calling customer services, but all they did was direct me here.

Does the latest version support the installation of IMVU?  All previous versions haven't, even though I was told they did.  I stopped trying after version 12, but would like, if possible, to try again.

Thank you in advance.

Howard.

Comment: The title reads `Latest version & IMVU`. If you need help with another problem, please feel free to [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) or [search](http://askubuntu.com/search) for an already answered one.

Answer (score 1):

### IMVU on Linux

1. Install WINE. 0.9.45 and earlier, has a problem where 
   chat bubbles are too small to read.

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
`sudo apt-get install wine`

2. Save the IMVU installer to disk from [here](http://avatars.imvu.com/signup/download/).
3. Run the IMVU installer:

`wine InstallIMVU_526.0_st.exe`

4. Choose a directory to install IMVU. I chose my home directory (so ~/imvu).
5. Now run the client:

`wine ~/imvu/IMVUClient.exe`

6. Be sure to select "OpenGL" or "Standard Graphics" from the Settings menu, because Direct3D support is wonky.

[Source](http://www.imvu.com/catalog/modules.php?op=modload&name=phpbb2&file=viewtopic.php&t=160996).
Also there is a [platinum rating on IMVU 4XX series on WineHQ with Wine v1.7](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2697).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create a installation/live flash drive from windows is with programs like [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) or [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/). Those programs download the installation image (iso, etc.) themselves and write it to the flash drive.

Comment: Tried this, even downloaded the new Rufus version, then downloaded the Ubuntu ISO file again & tried to create a bootable USB with it.  Rufus didn't recognise ANY of the Ubuntu ISO files i've downloaded.   Ubuntu used to mail disks out, but when I rang them to ask for one, they said I should try this site.  Is there anywhere I can get Ubuntu on disk from?   Much appreciation for the prompt reply.    Howard.